# Newly installed inline valves won't turn off / leaking

Tags: irrigation

I'm trying to install a brand new system for 2 drip irrigation lines. I've gone through 6 valves now and they all seem to have issues. I'm thinking I'm completely missing something.

The latest valve leaks from where the solenoid screws in, and also won't close.

Last Summer I installed 4 valves (I originally planned to plant sod this Spring but we ended up changing our minds to use artificial turf, hence going from 4 to 2) and had them all working. This Spring I went to test them, they were all having issues. 2 of them were visually cracked on the top, maybe from freezing? The other 2 just wouldn't turn off. Thinking that they might have all been damaged during the winter, I bought 2 more and rebuilt the manifold. Now 1 seems to be working but the other is having the issues above.

I've loosened the bleed screws, disassembled the valves to make sure there's no dirt or rocks in there. Everything looks fine.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6QoCkOTfMItMVRN8L1xNdQoNE7zowhm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you able to post some photos as well, videos are time-consuming's to watch